# return display instead of value using jquery jeditable with select and loadurl

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jeditable

I have been using the [jeditable library](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/in-place-editing-with-selects) for edit in place and it is working well in most cases.  However, I now have a problem trying to show the selected text instead of the selected value when using the loadurl parameter.  I've tried all of the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561503/jeditable-display-option-text-and-not-value-after-submit) however, they don't seem to work with loadurl instead of data.  Here is the pertinent code below, and I also have a working (for the most part - except for this issue) [test link here](http://telnestest.commandlink.com/test/edit_contact_test.html)

```
$('.editableContact').editable(
function(value, settings) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        'type':'POST',
        'url':'/test/update.php',
        'data':$(this).attr('id')+'='+value,
        'cache':false,
        'success':function(rjson) {
            //r=JSON.parse(rjson);
            //console.log(r);
            //We could do a hacky solution here to over-write the cell data, requiring another lookup on the server when posting. 
        }
    });
    return 'Display of Selected Option (value is:'+value+')';
    //normal return: return(value);

    //None of these work:
    //return $(this).html(settings.data[value]);
    //return settings.data[value];            
    //jQuery.parseJSON(settings.data)[value];                    
},


{
placeholder:'Double Click to Edit',
submit  : 'save',
cancel : 'x',
event : 'dblclick',
type : 'select',
loadurl : '/test/getContactsJson.php'
});
```

Any help is appreciated - thank you!